# pandas find all exact 4 consecutive digits from string

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a large text file that contains the text pattern, from that file I make a pandas data frame like below, from this pattern column I want to select a pattern that contains digits and the length of the **consecutive digits is exactly 4**.

For example, **a1234bc5678** is accepted and we can get two new 4 digit patterns from it e.g. **1234** and **5678** but **a12345** is not accepted because the length of the consecutive digit is **5**, not **4**.

```
print (df.sample(20))

              pattern
13457358     187019980
9892646         920204
2258941        dong998
5792706     diao511001
9144372       a2805938
15519502       YUEH008
15831448     752099429
15659305     469919209
13769825      majunsui
3446320       sishenD2
12970622     woaini123
11633295      guswjddl
12708217  342423198706
2079106     zj87755202
12551254   mxt19950626
4572063        1985625
7805173     theend0512
484820      jzm5583385
15017582       1981122
10868176      30061984
```

**What I have tried:** It's a single string that produces the wrong output for me because I only want the **exact 4 consecutive digits**. Also, I need to do it on pandas data frame if I can get it done.

```
text = '1234sunwei198734'
postcodes = re.findall('\d{4}',text)
print(postcodes)
```

Finally I did this way,

```
df2['pins'] = df2['pattern'].apply(lambda x: re.findall('(?<!\d)\d{4}(?!\d)',x))
df3 = df2[df2['pins'].apply(lambda x: len(x)) > 0]
```

Comment: You might be looking for `(?<!\d)\d{4}(?!\d)`, that is two negative lookarounds on both sides.

Comment: By "consecutive digits" do you mean digits that count up like "1234" or do you just mean any four digits together, e.g. "5481"?

Comment: any exact 4 digits sir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following your description, you might be looking for

```
(?<!\d)\d{4}(?!\d)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/AI262e/1/).

Comment: I just tested and it seems it's working sir, can you suggest How can I do it on pandas columns and create new columns based on the all-matched group? I think I need lambda but how do I know how many groups I matched?

Comment: @AlwaysSunny: I am no profi when it comes to `pandas` but you'll probably have a column with a list then as the groups may vary. In one entry, you'll have zero matches when in another entry there might be four matches. Imo, this is best handled with a list in combination with `str.extract(...)`.

Comment: Why `(?<!\d)` instead of `\D`? This answer does nothing to match consecutive digits, just digits.

Comment: @Vulwsztyn: With `\D` you match one character whereas with a negative lookbehind, you do not. Test `\D\d{4}\D` with `1234` and you will get no match - see https://regex101.com/r/9Zhpt0/1

Answer (score 2):

I think the best regex for the task would be

`(?<!\d)(1234|2345|3456|4567|5678|6789|7890|8901|9012|0123)(?!\d)`

Of course you could remove what you do not want

If you do not want to explicitly state the 4 consecutive digits pattern you can use less effective means like:

- find all 4 letter strings of digits with e.g. `\D(\d{4})\D`
- check if they are consecutive

Comment: First, this is not really a regular expression, just an alternation of possible matches. Plus, e.g. `1234` will with your above expression. In the end, OP is looking for lookarounds.

Comment: It is a regular expression, the fact that it doesn't look so doesn't mean it is not

Comment: Of course it is an expression - albeit not very elegant and possibly too restrictive.

Comment: How can it be too restrictive?

Answer (score 2):

While the regex already been given, but answering to your comment with pandas column..

### sample Dataset from your post:

```
>>> df1
         pattern
0      187019980
1         920204
2        dong998
3     diao511001
4       a2805938
5        YUEH008
6      752099429
7      469919209
8       majunsui
9       sishenD2
10     woaini123
11      guswjddl
12  342423198706
13    zj87755202
14   mxt19950626
15       1985625
16    theend0512
17    jzm5583385
18       1981122
19      30061984
```

Applying regex to pandas column ie `pattern` here, you can use below syntax which basically returns a list object like below..

```
>>> df1['pattern'].str.findall(r'(?<!\d)\d{4}(?!\d)')
0         []
1         []
2         []
3         []
4         []
5         []
6         []
7         []
8         []
9         []
10        []
11        []
12        []
13        []
14        []
15        []
16    [0512]    <-- this is your matched pattern
17        []
18        []
19        []
Name: pattern, dtype: object
```

So, you can convert these null list objects to string which will becom `NaN` then and the drop all them as you need only matching  value..

```
>>> df1['pattern'].str.findall(r'(?<!\d)\d{4}(?!\d)').str[0].dropna()
#  df1['pattern'].str.extract(r'((?<!\d)+\d{4})+(?!\d)').dropna()
16    0512
```

### Better approach for the last bit of your Post:

Just to the better solution which you required and doing with your approach by importing `re` module, that's not required, you simply can do that as follows. though choice is your :-) ..

```
>>> df1['pins'] = df1['pattern'].str.findall(r'(?<!\d)\d{4}(?!\d)')
>>> df1[df1['pins'].apply(lambda x: len(x)) > 0]
       pattern    pins
16  theend0512  [0512]
```

Comment: Thanks, @Karn, for your answer, though I've sorted it out. I appreciate your effect sir.

Comment: @AlwaysSunny, you are welcome, glad to know you sorted out though. i am curious how you achieved it.

Comment: Added on my main question above